How to set Application Insights from appsettings.json configuration in Azure Function App (dotnet-isolated)?
I want to configure Application Insights logging level using appsettings.json, like I do for ASP.NET Core web apps.
By default, the Application Insights SDK adds a "warning" logging level filter, which can be seen in the image below.
I have read that to configure Application Insights logging, it's not sufficient to set a default logging level using Logging.LogLevel.Default:, instead it must be specified explicitly: Logging.ApplicationInsights.LogLevel.Default:.
However, even with explicit configuration, I still observe the default "warning" filter, and I need to remove it manually in ConfigureLogging().
What am I doing wrong?
Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication((context, builder) => { })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        var environment = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ENVIRONMENT", "development");

        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    ...
    .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Default ApplicationInsights logging filter
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
        builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information);
    })
    .Build();

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}



Did you try configuring the application insights logging in host.json?

That only applies to the Function host, not the isolated worker. And yes, I configured it there too

Configure Application insights in Isolated Azure functions using appsettings.json.
appsettings.json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "884669a2-08ea-46d3-9fe1-104311129c82"
  }
}

Note: You can also configure log levels in appsettings.json.
Program.cs:

Configure App Insights logging to log the messages with required severity level (Warning/Information/Debug/Error etc.,)

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var configuration = context.Configuration;
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
        });
    }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {        
        loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights();
        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Function.cs:
 [Function("Function1")]
 public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("This is an INFORMATION log message.");
     _logger.LogWarning("This is a WARNING log message.");
     _logger.LogError("This is an ERROR log message.");
     _logger.LogTrace("This is a TRACE log message.");
     _logger.LogDebug("This is a DEBUG log message.");
     _logger.LogCritical("This is a CRITICAL log message.");

     return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
 }


Able to log the messages with severity level >3(Error logs):

Query:
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| where timestamp > datetime("2024-09-22T12:09:27.658Z") and timestamp < datetime("2024-09-23T12:09:27.658Z")
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100



You don't address the default rule created by Application Insights SDK to only log levels of warning and above?
